# why lmerTest gives different p value when data is too small?

Tags: lme4, lmertest

I'm new in statistics and this package. I expected that the p value should be the same if my data multiply or divide by the same number, for example, all *10 or all *100.

But since my data is too small(~10^-9), the p value is almost 1 at the beginning. But when I multiply the data (the 'x' in the test), the p value decreased until data became ~10^-5 and then the p value wouldn't change.

```
test= lmer(x ~ a + b +c + (1|rep), data=data)

   Estimate   Std. Error     df    t value   Pr(>|t|)
a2  -5.783e-09  1.232e-09  8.879e-05  -4.693    0.999            (raw data)
a2  -5.783e-08  1.232e-08  6.177e-03  -4.693    0.971            (raw data*10)
a2  -5.783e-07  1.232e-07  3.473e-01  -4.693    0.397            (raw data*100)
a2  -5.783e-06  1.232e-06  7.851e+00  -4.693  0.00164 **         (raw data*1000)
a2  -5.783e-05  1.232e-05  9.596e+01  -4.693 8.95e-06 ***        (raw data*10000)
a2  -0.0005783  0.0001232 95.9638425  -4.693 8.95e-06 ***        (raw data*100000)
```

I don't understand why these p values change to be constant. Could someone kindly explain it for me?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but a statistical question, so it would be more appropriate on CrossValidated, which is the stats section of the website. But to answer your question, you wouldn't expect the p-value to be the same if you have the same patterns in different amounts of data. As you are modelling the mean, and the standard error of that mean gets smaller with increased sample size, you would expect smaller p-values with more data, all else being equal

Comment: Here is an article that may be useful: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-relationship-between-significance-power-sample-size-effect-size-899fcf95a76d

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your answer but thanks firstly. I didn't change the sample size. The sample is constant. I just changed the value. For example, at first I have 6 value(the 'x' in the question), 1*10^-9, 1.1*10^-9,1.2*10^-9, 1.1*10^-9,1.15*10^-9, 1*10^-9 (not my real data), and now the pvalue is 0.999. But when I multiply them into 1*10^-8, 1.1*10^-8,1.2*10^-8, 1.1*10^-8,1.15*10^-8, 1*10^-8, and now the pvalue is 0.971.

Comment: But when the data is 1*10^-5, 1.1*10^-5,1.2*10^-5, 1.1*10^-5,1.15*10^-5, 1*10^-5, or they are 1*10^-4, 1.1*10^-4,1.2*10^-4, 1.1*10^-4,1.15*10^-4, 1*10^-4, or still *10, 1*10^-3, 1.1*10^-3,1.2*10^-3, 1.1*10^-3,1.15*10^-3, 1*10^-3, and so on, the p value are constantly 8.95e-06 and never changed then.

Comment: I just not understand, why when the data is too small, when I multiply them, the p value changed. But when it reached a scale ~10^-5, even I just multiply them in the same way, the p value will not change like before.

Comment: I found the difference was because the df evaluated by lmerTest varied when my dependent variable value too small. I still don't know how lmerTest evaluate df, but I change to use pbkrtest and the p value is stable now.

Comment: Looking at this again, it's apparent that the t-value is always the same, but the estimation of the degrees of freedom (df) is changing. To understand why that is, we need more information. Please see this page on creating a minimal working example, and I will do my best to help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after a bit of digging, I think that I have found a solution and an explanation. As you can see in your example, the t-value is not changing. The changes in p-value are due to changes in the estimated degrees of freedom. The default method for this is the Satterthwaite method, which according to this post from one of the authors of the package depends on the dependent variable (see the post here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342848/satterthwaite-degrees-of-freedom-in-a-mixed-model-change-drastically-depending-o)

Now, within a normal range of orders of magnitude, the degrees of freedom do not change and the p-values remain constant. You approached this from the other direction in your example, noting that the numbers stopped changing after a certain point (when the numbers in the DV were sufficiently large). Here I show that they are stable using an example from the iris package included with R:

```
# Preparing data
d <- iris
d$width <- d$Sepal.Width
d$Species <- as.factor(d$Species)

# Creating slightly smaller versions of the DV
d$length <- d$Sepal.Length
d$length_10 <- d$Sepal.Length/10
d$length_1e2 <- d$Sepal.Length/1e2
d$length_1e3 <- d$Sepal.Length/1e3

# fitting the models
m1 <- lmer(length ~ width + (1|Species),data = d)
m2 <- lmer(length_10 ~ width + (1|Species),data = d)
m3 <- lmer(length_1e2 ~ width + (1|Species),data = d)
m4 <- lmer(length_1e3 ~ width + (1|Species),data = d)

# The coefficients are all the same
> summary(m1)$coefficients
             Estimate Std. Error         df  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.4061671  0.6683080   3.405002 5.096703 1.065543e-02
width       0.7971543  0.1062064 146.664820 7.505711 5.453404e-12
> summary(m2)$coefficients
              Estimate Std. Error         df  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.34061671 0.06683080   3.405002 5.096703 1.065543e-02
width       0.07971543 0.01062064 146.664820 7.505711 5.453404e-12
> summary(m3)$coefficients
               Estimate  Std. Error         df  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.034061671 0.006683079   3.405003 5.096703 1.065542e-02
width       0.007971543 0.001062064 146.664820 7.505711 5.453405e-12
> summary(m4)$coefficients
                Estimate   Std. Error         df  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.0034061671 0.0006683079   3.405003 5.096703 1.065542e-02
width       0.0007971543 0.0001062064 146.664820 7.505711 5.453405e-12
```

However, your numbers are much smaller than this, so I made much smaller versions of the DV to try and re-create your example. As you can see, the degrees of freedom start approaching zero which causes the p-values to move towards one.

```
# Much smaller numbers
d$length_1e6 <- d$Sepal.Length/1e6
d$length_1e7 <- d$Sepal.Length/1e7
d$length_1e8 <- d$Sepal.Length/1e8

# fitting the models
m5 <- lmer(length_1e6 ~ width + (1|Species),data = d)
m6 <- lmer(length_1e7 ~ width + (1|Species),data = d)
m7 <- lmer(length_1e8 ~ width + (1|Species),data = d)

# Here we recreate the problem
> summary(m5)$coefficients
                Estimate   Std. Error        df  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.406167e-06 6.683079e-07 0.5618686 5.096703 0.2522273
width       7.971543e-07 1.062064e-07 0.6730683 7.505711 0.1599534
> summary(m6)$coefficients
                Estimate   Std. Error         df  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.406167e-07 6.683080e-08 0.01224581 5.096703 0.9461743
width       7.971543e-08 1.062064e-08 0.01229056 7.505711 0.9415154
> summary(m7)$coefficients
                Estimate   Std. Error           df  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.406167e-08 6.683080e-09 0.0001784636 5.096703 0.9988162
width       7.971543e-09 1.062064e-09 0.0001784738 7.505711 0.9987471
```

A possible solution to this is to use another approximation method, Kenward-Roger. Let's take the model with the smallest transformation of the DV here. we can do that with the following code:

```
summary(m7, ddf="Kenward-Roger")$coefficients
                Estimate   Std. Error         df  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.406167e-08 6.687077e-09   3.408815 5.093656 1.064475e-02
width       7.971543e-09 1.064752e-09 146.666335 7.486759 6.053660e-12
```

As you can see, with this method the numbers from the smallest version of our transformation now match the stable numbers from the larger transformations. Understanding exactly why small numbers are a problem for the Satterthwaite method is beyond my understanding of the methods employed by lmerTest method, but I know at least one of them is on here and might be able to provide additional insight. I suspect it might be related to underflow, as your numbers are very small, but I can't be sure.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly and detailed answer! I tried Kenward-Roger approach in lmerTest and the results were stable now. I guess underflow may be a possible answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help! And yeah, I'm not sure exactly why, as I'm not a statistician, but at least the other method provides stable results